# CSS not working with html file in django, why is it not working?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, django

My CSS file does not seem to be working in Django and I am not sure why. I have tried many different ways to get it to work but it's still not working. I have added `{%load static%}`on top of the HTML file and my css file is named `main.css` which is in a folder called static. I have also added the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" >
```

to my html file. Also in my setting.py file I have added this line

```
STATICFILES_DIR=[
    "/Users/yaminhimani/Desktop/tweetybird/static",
]
```

in order to find the CSS file. After doing all this why would the styling still now show up for my website?

Comment: is `django.contrib.staticfiles` included in the installed apps? Parhaps this page will help you out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Also, `STATICFILES_DIRS` seems to be for multiple static folders, not tied to a particular app. Though you forget to add the `S` at the end of `DIRS`

Comment: How do I check if django.contrib.staticfiles included in the installed apps?

Comment: It should be in your settings.py:
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]`

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach and see if it can help you. Django v3

settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may already be in your `settings.py` file but it may be worth it to check:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If that's good, then it could be the folder setup. The Django documentation recommends nesting the CSS files in the following way:

```
app_name/static/app_name/main.css
```